# Js RegEx do not recognize accented letters (utf-8)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, unicode

Node.js 10.8.0 on Windows 10 64 bits
Need to recognize strings that contain non-alpabetic characters:

```
let a = "train"
/\W/u.test(a) // false
a = "non-good"
/\W/u.test(a) // true
```

So far so good. But this does not work if the string contains an accented letter:

```
a = "niño"
/\W/u.test(a) // true!?
```

Note I use the 'u' modifier to make it work with Unicode.

Bug or feature?

Obviously, I can write the test as:

```
/[^a-zA-Zñ]/u.test(a)
```

Adding all the accented characters, but does not seems the right way.
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: [This article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) might be able to help. I haven't used RE to match accented characters, but this seems to have a lot of good information on it.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Seems `/\P{L}/u.test(a)` does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

**Apparently, feature.**

According to MDN:

> **\W**
>
> Matches any character that is not a word character **from the basic
>   Latin alphabet**. Equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]`.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

I can not find any source claiming that the `u` flag should change that behavior.